# CSS menu on the sides of DIV

Tags: jquery, html, css

What would be the easiest and "cleanest" way to create a menu like this one:
[image]

Aka, there is one DIV (with fixed width) in the middle and 3 links on each side like attached.

I am sure this can be done with absolute positioning and rotating each :nth-child item, but that could get messy and i was wondering does anybody know any cleaner solution?

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="text">
     Lorem Ipsum  Lorem Ipsum
     Lorem Ipsum  Lorem Ipsum
     Lorem Ipsum  Lorem Ipsum
</div>
```

Fiddle is something like this : https://jsfiddle.net/am2o3og1/

Comment: For those slight rotations you will have to use `:nth-child`, but if you use SASS or LESS you can speed that up immensely (and not worry about the output). The left-hand, right-hand are a bit dependent on what you want, floats can do the trick, but so can absolute positioning.

Answer (score 2):

HTML

```
   <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="text">
         Lorem Ipsum  Lorem Ipsum
         Lorem Ipsum  Lorem Ipsum
         Lorem Ipsum  Lorem Ipsum
    </div>
    <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    </ul>
```

CSS:

```
.text {
    width: 130px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: lightblue;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    float:left;
}
.menu {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float:left;
}
.menu li {

    -ms-transform: rotate(7deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(7deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(7deg);
}

.menu li + li, .text + .menu li + li {

    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(0deg);

}

.menu li + li + li {

    -ms-transform: rotate(-7deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-7deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(-7deg);

}


.text + .menu li {

     -ms-transform: rotate(-7deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-7deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(-7deg);
}


.text + .menu li + li + li {

    -ms-transform: rotate(7deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(7deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(7deg);

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/am2o3og1/2/